# array reallaction segfault with list

Tags: arrays, c, linux-kernel, segmentation-fault, realloc

I try to maintain the following data structure:

```
typedef struct {
    int channel_id;
    unsigned int minor;
} private_data_type;
typedef struct {
    char msg_value[msg_len];
    short len;
    unsigned int channel_id;

} msg;
typedef struct
{
    int len;
    msg ** array_of_msg;
} array_list;
```

I tried to enlarge the list simply by reallocating the array list:

```
int  add2list(array_list ** minor_arr,int minor,msg * new_msg)
{
    void *newPlace;
    array_list *  list=minor_arr[minor];
    list->len++;
    printk(" new length %d,total size %ld",list->len,list->len*sizeof(msg ));
    debug_pointer(list->array_of_msg);
    newPlace= krealloc(list->array_of_msg, list->len*sizeof(msg **), GFP_KERNEL);
    printk("resize complete");
    if(newPlace==NULL)
        return 0;

    list->array_of_msg= newPlace;
    list->array_of_msg[list->len-1]=new_msg;
    return 1;

}
```

for some unknown reasons I get the following segfault:

```
[   26.583607] 00000000fb161d4a
[   26.583611] BUG: unable to handle page fault for address: ffffda3727cdcd88
[   26.583613] #PF: supervisor read access in kernel mode
[   26.583614] #PF: error_code(0x0000) - not-present page
[   26.583615] PGD 0 P4D 0 
[   26.583617] Oops: 0000 [#1] SMP PTI
[   26.583619] CPU: 0 PID: 1110 Comm: message_sender. Tainted: G           OE     5.4.0-58-generic #64~18.04.1-Ubuntu
[   26.583620] Hardware name: innotek GmbH VirtualBox/VirtualBox, BIOS VirtualBox 12/01/2006
[   26.583623] RIP: 0010:__ksize+0x39/0xe0
[   26.583624] Code: 80 48 01 d7 0f 82 b2 00 00 00 48 c7 c2 00 00 00 80 48 2b 15 09 1a 19 01 48 01 fa 48 c1 ea 0c 48 c1 e2 06 48 03 15 e7 19 19 01 <48> 8b 42 08 48 8d 48 ff a8 01 48 0f 45 d1 48 8b 4a 08 48 8d 41 ff
[   26.583625] RSP: 0018:ffffa22dc03ebde8 EFLAGS: 00010282
[   26.583627] RAX: 0000000000000010 RBX: 000000007373622e RCX: 0000000000000006
[   26.583628] RDX: ffffda3727cdcd80 RSI: 0000000000000008 RDI: 00000000f373622e
[   26.583629] RBP: ffffa22dc03ebdf0 R08: 000000000000022f R09: 0000000000000004
[   26.583629] R10: 0000000000000000 R11: 0000000000000001 R12: 0000000000000008
[   26.583630] R13: ffff9246f8744840 R14: 0000000000000cc0 R15: 000000000000000b
[   26.583632] FS:  00007f3015b7b4c0(0000) GS:ffff9246fda00000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
[   26.583632] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
[   26.583633] CR2: ffffda3727cdcd88 CR3: 0000000077452001 CR4: 00000000000606f0
[   26.583637] Call Trace:
[   26.583640]  ? ksize+0x19/0x30
[   26.583642]  krealloc+0x2e/0xc0
[   26.583646]  add2list+0x5a/0x88 [message_slot]
[   26.583648]  device_write+0xf6/0x126 [message_slot]
[   26.583650]  __vfs_write+0x1b/0x40
[   26.583651]  vfs_write+0xb1/0x1a0
[   26.583653]  ksys_write+0xa7/0xe0
[   26.583654]  __x64_sys_write+0x1a/0x20
[   26.583657]  do_syscall_64+0x57/0x190
[   26.583659]  entry_SYSCALL_64_after_hwframe+0x44/0xa9
[   26.583661] RIP: 0033:0x7f3015687224
```

Does anyone spot my mistake?
it should have enlrage the list's array and enlarge the length by 1.

Comment: it's ran on the kernel, so I can't run valngrind.

Comment: Shouldn't `list->len*sizeof(msg **)` be `list->len*sizeof(msg *)`?

Comment: both are 8 no? @AugustKarlstrom

Comment: Most likely the heap has already be **corrupted** when you cal `krealloc`. With such **incomplete** code it is difficult to say where the corruption has been done. "Does anyone spot my mistake?" - Note, that intention of Stack Overflow is NOT to find things which has been missed. Intention of Stack Overflow is to find things which you don't **know** and explain them.

Comment: @Tsyvarev can you explain me how to find invalid writes in the kernel? I usually would use valgrind, what else can I do?

Comment: You may use KASAN for that purpose: https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v5.3/dev-tools/kasan.html.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I didn't understand how to install it on my kernel. I didn't find the config file CONFIG_KASAN = y

Comment: FYI: this is not a segfault. It's in fact a kernel oops as you're running your code inside the kernel ...

Comment: Looking at your two questions I suspect that you have unclear understanding what `** foo` notation means in C.